# Using a user folder for python3 packages with pip3

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install and use python3 packages to `/home/myname/pp` folder. I should be able to run python3 from anywhere. Also, pip3 should be able to update the packages in this folder. I should also be able to copy this folder to a new Linux system and it should work there as well (by changing PYTHONPATH there).

I searched and found following options:

```
pip install -t <direct directory> <package> # I prefer this.
```

and

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
```

or use:

```
virtualenv
```

and then I need to do:

```
echo 'export PYTHONPATH="/home/myname/pp:$PYTHONPATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

What should be my approach for these requirements? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install -t <direct directory> <package>
```

Will install the package globally in the given directory. 
    pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
Will run the package's `setup.py` with the given parameters, as mentioned in the pip's help:

> --install-option   Extra arguments to be supplied to the setup.py install command (use like
>   --install-option="--install-scripts=/usr/local/bin"). Use multiple --install-
>                                 option options to pass multiple options to setup.py install. If you are using an option with a directory path,
>   be sure to use absolute path.

The recommended way to do to install packages is to use a virtual environment. It keeps your global packages sanitized, in case you want the same package but different versions for it in two different projects for example.

`virtualenv` basically creates a folder for where to store the installed packages. 
In a linux-based system, you would have to run the `virtualenv` commmand to create the folder and after that "activate" it.

```
virtualenv my_virtual_environment
source my_virtual_environment/bin/activate
```

You will notice that the environment's name will appear at the end of shell line. What `activate` does is simply changing some paths in your `PATH` environment variable to point to your current virtual environment folder.
It will still used the system's python interpreter but when trying to import packages in your program, it will look in the virtual environment's folder first.
To return to the global python packages, just type `deactivate`.

If you want the environment you're using to be active right when you start the terminal, add the `source` command to your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`. I recommend using the absolute path to the python virtual environment.

If you're working on multiple projects and want to keep the packages separate from each other, create multiple virtual environments and just switch to them. You could take a look at [virtalenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which makes starting the virtual environment when you open the terminal and switching between other environments really easy.

Comment: I want to install packages for global use only. Hence I like `pip install -t <direct directory> <package>`. But will I be able to copy this folder to a new Linux system? I can transfer the packages folder to new Linux system in R language ( https://www.r-project.org/ ) which avoids downloading on every system.

Comment: You could do that. Keep in mind that python looks for the for packages which can be found in `sys.path`. Either move those packages to the folder `site-packages` where it's looking for them or add the folder's path to `sys.path`.